# Overlapping GPS track data in sea-map mismatch problem. QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gps, shoreline

Working on QGIS version 2.1817 "Las Palmas" I ran into a spatial mismatch between GPS track data with shoreline data sourced from GSHHS* to make a study site map of an inland sea. The extent of the shoreline data is big, its "global".

The tracks display correctly in Google Earth.
The problem I have is that the tracks pass trough land, in particular there's a mismatch in an area in the south. Here the surveys navigated around the island, which isn't shown in my map.
If I move the track data to be closer to the island, then a larger fraction of the tracks come into shore.

What I've tried is selecting different CRS I have reasons to believe are correct for this area, and am making sure that all layers have the same CRS.
I also have "on the fly conversion" option enabled.

I attach an basic image of my map from QGIS.
How can I make the layers match ?

*GSHHG website https://www.soest.hawaii.edu/pwessel/gshhg/

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  It emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question for GIS SE.

Comment: In my experience, any errors in CRS or similar give a simple X, Y (and Z) shift on a local scale (up to a few kilometers).  If you shift all your tracks to the left a little bit to make them go around the tiny island at the bottom I think you'll find shore-line clashes in bigger island, which might indicate that GSHHG  has the tiny island in the wrong location.  Is that possible?

Comment: QGIS 2.18 is outdated since 2018, so I would advice installing the current version (3.20). How far inland are your GPS tracks at maximum? It doesn't look like a CRS problem. Isn't it possible that the shorelines are just genralized in a way that they appear where there should be water? So which of your data is more precise and accurate: GPS tracks or land polygons? So getting a more precise dataset would solve the problem? How does it look with an OpenStreetMap or Google Satellite basemap in the background? Would changing the land polygons be an acceptable solution to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You global shoreline dataset is not very precise. A difference of several hundred meters between the actual shore and the data's shoreline seems to be normal for this data, see screenshot. So there's no CRS problem involved. By the way: handling CRS is much easier in QGIS 3.X. You use a very old version, I recommend to get the newest version.

So the ships do not actually travel over land, just the land polygons are drawn inexactly and in some places reach to the water body where your ships passed.

You can use OpenStreetMap data instead, it is much more precise.

*Pink line: shoreline from your dataset on a Google satellite image. As you can see, the pink line is around 300 m from the actual shore:*
[image]